# React js webpage with language translate function(manual)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a react project which the webpage include function of translate the language button (Eng/Chinese) 
Currently i still on the beginner state which use `chineseHomePage.js` and `EngHomePage.js` to create every pages, yes it seem dumb. Can anyone recommend or give me a suggestion any way i can do? 
Like by only 1 `HomePage.js` which include 2 language and use 1 of the section (eng) when call? 
I have try to research on youtube but i cant find similar project. Pls provide me some sources and example of coding.

Comment: You should search for "i18n", you'll find plenty of solutions to add translation to your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For translations you have solutions like [react-18next](https://react.i18next.com/) or [formatjs](https://formatjs.io/).
In this case, you are going to have only one HomePage.js, and translate the strings inside that page to how many languages you want, like this:

```
<h2>{t('Welcome to React')}</h2>
```

You are going to have a separate file with the translations on json format.

```
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      "Welcome to React": "Welcome to React and react-i18next"
    }
  },
  fr: {
    translation: {
      "Welcome to React": "Bienvenue à React et react-i18next"
    }
  }
};
```

You should read the documentation, they have a step by step start guide.